# Solving a wave equation using Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Consider the wave equation

$$
\partial^2_tu-\Delta u=F, \text{ on } (0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^m\\
u(0,\cdot)=f,\partial_t u(0,\cdot)=g
$$
Show that for $f,g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and $F\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^{m+1}_+)$ the solution can be expressed as
$$
u(t)=R_0(t)f+R_1(t)g+\int_0^tR_1(t-s)F(s)ds,
$$
where
$$
(\mathcal{F}(R_0(t)f))(k)=\cos t|k|(\mathcal{F}f)(k),(\mathcal{F}(R_1(t)g)(\xi)=\frac{\sin(t|k|)}{|k|}(\mathcal{F}g)(k).
$$

I tried this two different ways, and got stuck at the same point both times. Here is the first way:

Take the Fourier transform in space to get the ODE
$$
\hat{u}''+|k|^2\hat{u}=\hat{F}.
$$
Solving the homogeneous equation we get the complementary solution
$$
\hat{u}_c=A\cos|k|t+B\sin|k|t.
$$
The variation of parameters formula then gives the particular solution
$$
\hat{u}_p=-cos|k|t\int\frac{\sin|k|t}{|k|}\hat{F}dt+\sin|k|t\int\frac
{\cos|k|t}{|k|}\hat{F} dt.
$$

So then
$$
\hat{u}=\hat{u}_c+\hat{u}_p=A\cos|k|t+B\sin|k|t-cos|k|t\int\frac{\sin|k|t}{|k|}\hat{F}dt+\sin|k|t\int\frac
{\cos|k|t}{|k|} \hat{F}dt.
$$

If I apply the initial conditions on just the complementary solution I get $A=\hat{f}$ and $B=\frac{\hat{g}}{|k|}$, which looks like what we want to get. But I feel like I should be able to apply the initial conditions to the general solution and get the same thing. When I try that, however, I get something messy involving integrals I can't integrate.

From the solution we are given it seems like we need to use convolution for the inverse Fourier transform of the last part, but I can't quite seem to get there. I'm also confused by what $R_1(t)$ is. We're told that the Fourier transform of $R_1(t)g$ is $\frac{\sin|k|t}{|k|}(\mathcal{F}g)$ but that doesn't tell us that the Fourier transform of $R_1(t)$ is $\frac{\sin|k|t}{|k|}$, so how can we express it?

The second way I tried to solve the question was, after taking the FT, I let $z=\hat{u}'+i|k|\hat{u}$, showed that this solves the equation $z'-i|k|z=\hat{F}$, found the solution to that, split it into real and imaginary parts, and equated the imaginary part with $|k|\hat{u}$. This gave me

$$
\hat{u}=\frac{1}{|k|}\left[\sin|k|t+\sin|k|t\int\hat{F}\cos|k|tdt-\cos|k|t\int\hat{F}\sin|k|tdt\right]
$$

which is similar to the other answers, but without a $\cos$ term and the constant coefficients.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Wouldn't you get definite integrals in the particular solution, $$-\cos \lvert k\rvert t \int_0^t \frac{\sin \lvert k\rvert \tau}{\lvert k\rvert} \hat{F}(\tau,k)\,d\tau$$ and analogous for the other? That would give $\hat{u}_p$ initial conditions $0$.